# Not able to select Edit Text of fragments by touch

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-studio

I have added two edit text in my fragment and by user input I add this fragment to the frame layout of one of the activity..but I am not able to select the edit text by touch..

Here is the code of my fragment..

```
package com.example.pratik.myfail3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class BlankFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    public EditText editText5, editText6;
    public Button button2;
    public View.OnClickListener onClickListener;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of this fragment using
     * the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public BlankFragment() {

        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    public void Connect(View view) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction();
        //EditText editText5;
        //editText5=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        //EditText editText6 = (EditText) view.findViewById();
        //String ip2=editText5.getText().toString();
        //int port2=Integer.parseInt(editText6.getText().toString());
        //ip=ip2;
        //port=port2;
        //Thread thread1=new Thread(new ReceiverThread());
        //thread1.start();

        //Thread thread2=new Thread(new SenderThread(Synctoken));
        //thread2.start();
        //transaction.remove(addFragment);
        //transaction.commit();
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
        editText5 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        editText6 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        editText5.setOnClickListener(this);
        editText6.setOnClickListener(this);
        button2.setOnClickListener(this);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        //view.requestFocus();
        //view.setFocusable(true);
        //view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.editText5:
                editText5.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(getView(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                break;
            case R.id.editText6:
                editText5.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager img = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                img.showSoftInput(getView(), InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                mListener.onFragmentInteraction();
                break;
        }
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {

        // TODO: Update argument type and name

        public void onFragmentInteraction();
    }

}
```

Here is my xml code the fragment..

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:hint="IP Address"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:editable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="121dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:hint="PORT NO."
    android:inputType="number|text"
    android:textSize="24dp"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:numeric="integer"
    android:editable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="124dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Connect"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:background="@color/button_material_dark"
    android:onClick="Connect"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />


  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can use <requestfocus/> in xml itself and also point edit text to the next one on action done

Comment: Adding <requestfocus/> to the xml brings the cursor to the first edit Text .But i am not able to switch between the two edit texts .I mean by touching on the second edit text i amnot able to focus on it..

Comment: Are you sure that there is not a view over the editText? Then the user would not be able to click on the editText...

Comment: ya.There is a view over the edit Text..So,how can i bring this edit Text in front of that view?